# Help filling gridview from a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

I am trying to execute a stored procedure and place the information in a datagrid(without using the .net wizard) i want to do it manually. Using ado.net i believe. I am using vb.net and asp.net

```
 Public cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Public saoda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Public conn As New SqlConnection("    ")
    Dim saods As New DataSet

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yeartoget", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
        cmd.CommandText = "casof"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection = conn

        conn.Open()

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        ' Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

        GridView1.DataSource = saods

        saoda.FillSchema(saods, SchemaType.Mapped)

        GridView1.DataBind()
        conn.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

vvvvv

```
Dim pctofsales As New DataColumn
        pctofsales = New DataColumn("PCTofsales", GetType(Decimal))
        pctofsales.Expression = "IIF([YEsales] = 0, 0, [ASOFSales] / [YEsales])"
        saods1.Tables("salesasoftable").Columns.Add(pctofsales)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind a DataSet to a GridView - a SqlDataReader will suffice. That is, you could use the following:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yeartoget", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    cmd.CommandText = "casof"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = conn

    conn.Open()

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    GridView1.DataSource = reader
    GridView1.DataBind()

    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

However, if you want/need to use a DataTable, that's no big deal, either. The following snippet loads a reader into a DataTable:

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yeartoget", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
cmd.CommandText = "casof"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = conn

conn.Open()

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Dim myTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
myTable.Load(reader)

GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()

conn.Close()
```

Happy Programming!

Comment: thanks is it possible to select which columns i want to be retured or to use a dataset so i can make changes to the columns would i just bind the reader to a dataset thank you

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: If you want to specify what columns to display in the GridView, use the GridView's <Columns> collection and set its AutoGenerateFields property to False. You can also do it through the Designer - open the grid's Smart Tag and choose Edit Columns. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx

Comment: i kind of want to do something like the code i will post right now above

Comment: the reason is i am dealing with canceled sales, net sales and sales. Right now my stored procedure shows all three. I am trying to only show the columns related to net sales when the user selects net sales and when they select sales only the columns related to sales will be shown

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: You can programmatically show or hide GridView columns. For instance, to hide the first column you'd do: GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False. Perhaps you can have the Grid show ALL columns returned by the stored procedure by default, and then programmatically show/hide those columns you need to based on what type of report is being run?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: I updated my answer to include an example of how you could load a DataTable based on a SqlDataReader.